# UITableViewCell doesn't detect tap when I use heightForRowAtIndexPath: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a simple `UITableViewCell` thats height is set in the `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I'm using this method in 5 applications and it works everytime perfectly, however now I have some problems with it, when I'm using it, my cell's doesn't detects taps.

As I discovered it works perfectly in the projects that I created in Xcode 6, but it doesn't work in the project that I created in Xcode 7. What can cause this problem? Did something change with the `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method? It's really annoying, because I have no idea, it works still perfectly in my other apps(project created with Xcode6), but it doesn't want to work in my freshly created Xcode 7 project. When I remove it the cell starts detect the tap again, when I add it I can't even write out an `NSLog` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for cell taps.

What do I need to do? Maybe it's just something basic that I need to enable in IB, but couldn't figure it out.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    
    if(!self.itemCell) {
        self.itemCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    
    NSString *object = [self.stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 
    self.itemCell.itemTitle.text = object;

    
    [self.itemCell layoutIfNeeded];
    
    CGFloat height = [self.itemCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    
    return height+5;
}
```

(I also tried `cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` without any success.)

Comment: Never call `dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier` inside the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. It can lead to crashes caused by infinite recursion.

Comment: @rmaddy what should I do as an alternative? It works me perfectly in several apps.

Comment: It probably works because you save the result in an ivar which means it will only work if you have one row in your table view.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right, I have only one row and ivar :). But I think in this situation the issue is not this, it should be something Xcode related imo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once by removing all code of dequeing. I had a project like this and it was working fine .

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
NSString *object = [self.stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

self.itemCell.itemTitle.text = object;


[self.itemCell layoutIfNeeded];

CGFloat height = [self.itemCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

return height+5;
}
```

Hope this helps